# how use Scanner and push that values to an array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I want to push values from a `Scanner` to an `Array`. I want to know if this code is right. How to do if it is wrong? This is a method I call over and over again. So I want to store that user input values in an `Array`.

```
    String[] student_id = new String[150];  
    String studentId = "";

    System.out.print("Enter Student ID   : ");
    studentId = input.nextLine();
   
    student_id = studentId;
   
    for(int i =0;i<student_id.length;i++) {
       student_id[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: This code is reading one value into studentId  and then filling up the array with this value.

Comment: you are already doing that, but you should replace the line in your for loop by: student_id[i] = input.nextLine();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easy

```
String[] student_id=new String[150];        
    System.out.print("Enter Student ID   : ");
    for(int i =0;i<student_id.length;i++){
    student_id[i] = input.nextLine();
}
```